Scroll Magic transition issues with full screen background videos
I have an issue with animations on scroll magic being funky when scrolling back UP.
So in the JSFiddle attached you'll see the animations looks fine on the way down. However on the way up it sort of breaks and looks funky. Dummy videos in here for testing purposes.
Thanks for any help.
I was expecting the same scroll animations to happen on the way Up as they look on the way down.
https://jsfiddle.net/guyinthewoods/v05wzouh/5/
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({ triggerElement: ".section1", offset: 25, duration: "95%",})
            .setClassToggle(".section1 .copy, .section1 .background-video, .overlay", "visible")
            .addIndicators({name: "1 (duration: 0)"})
            .addTo(controller);


        var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({ triggerElement: ".section2", offset: 25, duration: "95%",})
            .setClassToggle(".section2 .copy, .section2 .background-video, .overlay", "visible")
            .addIndicators({name: "1 (duration: 0)"})
            .addTo(controller);

        var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({ triggerElement: ".section3", offset: 25, duration: "95%",})
            .setClassToggle(".section3 .copy, .section3 .background-video, .overlay", "visible")
            .addIndicators({name: "1 (duration: 0)"})
            .addTo(controller);

    });

